# Want to enforce specific order of methods execution of a class, when this class is used. Does exist a design pattern for this?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have a class that represents a process

```
internal class IntegrationWithSalesforce
{
    public IntegrationWithSalesforce()
    { // Initialize internal variables }

    public bool GetListOfCustomersToImport() { ... }
    public bool CreateSalesforceJob() { ... }
    public bool CreateJobBatches() { ... }
    public bool CloseSalesforceJob() { ... }    
    public void UpdateBatchesProcessingInfo() { ... }
    public bool AbortJob() { ... }
}
```

methods should be execute in specific order until you invoke CloseSalesforceJob.

I want to enforce this order of execution:
1- class initialization
2- call GetListOfCustomersToImport if true 
3- call CreateSalesforceJob if true
4- call CreateJobBatches if true
5- call CloseSalesforceJob
6- then keeps calling UpdateBatchesProcessingInfo until all batches states 
   have value Completed ,Failed

My first idea is have boolean variables that represent state(or execution )
and set the one related with method to true when method is called, or throw custom Exception ProcessOrderExecutionException if method is not the next in order.

For example:

```
// add this variable to my class
bool processInitialized = false;
bool customerSumaryListRetrieved = false;
bool salesforceJobSuccessfullyCreated = false;
bool salesforceBatchesSuccessfullyCreated = false;
```

a) method GetListOfCustomersToImport implementation

```
public bool GetListOfCustomersToImport()
{
    .....
    //at the end
    customerSumaryListRetrieved = true;
```

}

b) method CreateSalesforceJob

```
public bool CreateSalesforceJob()
{
    if(!customerSumaryListRetrieved)
        throw new ProcessOrderExecutionException();

    //at the end
    // method implementation
    salesforceJobSuccessfullyCreated = true;    
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? A design pattern, or a known implementation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If that's the only acceptable way to perform the action, then write a method that does exactly that, and make that the only public method for your class.  None of these other methods should be public if it's not acceptable for them to be called in any other way.

Comment: this assumes you don't need to do anything else in between steps

Comment: @aw04 There are plenty of ways of supporting that if needed; the OP hasn't indicated that that's a necessity.

Comment: @Servy that's the way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to achieve enforcement of a specific workflow. Here's one:

```
internal class IntegrationWithSalesforce
{
    public IntegrationWithSalesforce()
    { ... }
    public JobCreator GetListOfCustomersToImport() { ... }
}

class JobCreator()
{
    public JobBatchCreator CreateSalesForceJob() { ... }
}
```

... and so on.  Now you use it like this:

```
var integrator = new IntegrationWithSalesforce();
var jobCreator = integrator.GetListOfCustomersToImport();
if (jobCreator != null)
{
  var jobBatchCreator = jobCreator.CreateSaleforceJob();
  ...
}
```

And so on.  Since you can only call the later methods after the earlier methods, the workflow is imposed by the type system.

But frankly I think this is a bit over overkill. Your better bet would be to do what one of the other answers says. If there is a particular workflow you want imposed, then write a method that imposes that workflow, and make that the only public method.

Comment: I was overthinking this, your sample code and comment help me. I will go with @Servy suggestion. Make methods private and expose one that call them in desired order. Thanks.

Comment: @Eric: all those methods do not belong to the same class, so such approach does not satisfy requirement included in the question.

Comment: @Karol: Where the methods are *implemented* is an *implementation detail*. What the rules of the *line-of-business workflow* are is a *business requirement*. Don't fall into the trap of believing that those two things necessarily have anything to do with each other. The question is about techniques for constructing representations of workflows; my point is that there are many such techniques, each with pros and cons.

Comment: I completely agree with you that it should be an implementation detail but question is very clear here – a class represents process, methods that belong to this class should be executed in specific order. Requirements are very artificial so I would expect that you will explicitly deny them or try to propose something that satisfy them. for now your answer seems not to answer the question.

Comment: @Karol: Well then I encourage you to write an answer that you think does answer the question better.

Comment: Note that this approach would prevent a method from being called before an earlier method was called, but it wouldn't prevent a method in the chain from being called earlier in the process, nor would it stop someone from calling, say `CreateSaleforceJob`a second time after having already called later methods.  If the methods only ever produce values used later in the chain, none of this is a problem, but if they produce side effects (and some of the names imply that they are) then that could be a problem.

Comment: @Servy: That's a good point. In those cases I suppose you'd want to make every method idempotent.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is through a state machine (also known as state pattern, since you specifically asked for a design pattern). Basically, the state will restrict which methods can be called. You could for instance have five states, where first state accepts only the first method, and a call to it switches the state to the second state. Then second state accepts only the second method, etc., until you reach state five, which accepts any method and never switches to a different state.